# Unity} I can't find solution at build error System.ArgumentException

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, il2cpp

While building, the error below appears and the build does not work. Please give me a solution.

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path')
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at ApiUpdater.MovedFromOptimizer.Program.RealMain(String[] args)
   at ApiUpdater.MovedFromOptimizer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

sorry for my english.

i don't using 'path' in my scripts and build path is fine. i tried restart my project.

Comment: you do - where are you building to? what is your project location? if you have spaces, or non english characters, so pretty much antyhing not a-z0-9 is a bad thing